# Saving images with saveEventually on a parse backend

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm making an app with swift and parse backend.

I would like to save images to the backend. This works with the `saveInBackgroundWithBlock`method.
I've read there is a `saveEventually`method which saves the file to the backend if there is an internet connection otherwise it saves to the local device.

Can someone tell me if they already implemented this for PFFile objects, because i've this wasn't impelemented a 1 year ago.

I'm on parse sdk 1.6

Answer (score 0):

According to the Parse iOS SDK documentation, `saveEventually` is now supported on `PFObject` types as of version 1.6.1.

You have the option to either use `- (void)saveEventually` or `- (void)saveEventually:(PFBooleanResultBlock)callback` with a completion block for error handling.

http://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFObject.html#//api/name/saveEventually